# Google plus share API posting twice in wall

Tags: android, google-plus

I want to share some link into google+ wall. I have used `PlusShare.Builder`. I have followed this link https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/share/

```
shareButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
  // Launch the Google+ share dialog with attribution to your app.
  Intent shareIntent = new PlusShare.Builder(this)
      .setType("text/plain")
      .setText("Welcome to the Google+ platform.")
      .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://developers.google.com/+/"))
      .getIntent();

  startActivityForResult(shareIntent, 0);
}
});
```

**The problem is that I can see my post two times inside Google+.**

Comment: Add a Log line in the onclick event handler and see if by any chance this is being fired twice

Comment: @Lefteris thanks for your reply.. let me try it and let you know

Comment: @Lefteris I have checked Log comes only one time

Comment: Sorry, don't have any other ideas.

Comment: Sorry to bother, I actually have the same problem and I can't find any solution. Have you managed to solve this issue?

Comment: @MuraliGanesan - Was this issue solved?

Comment: @TheDevMan Till now i have not fixed this.